# Publishing to Red Hat JBoss has encountered a

Tags: java, eclipse, deployment, jboss

We are using Eclipse and JBoss EAP 6.1. I have an eclipse project (ear) that encompasses two other projects: a web project and a "normal" java project. Upon an attempt to deploy the .ear project to JBoss I recieve an error message in a pop-up window in Eclipse:

```
Publishing to Red Hat JBoss has encountered a Problem
Could not publish to the server.
```

When I click on the "Details" Button just after the message, I see

```
Could not publish to the server.
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

But no stack trace or any additional information is provided.
Could somebody help me, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in the missing deployment descriptor of the application. We added it and now deployment functions as expected